# Prevent function override in R

Tags: r, function, user-interface, overriding

I have started writing a GUI for R in tJava through rJava.

Since I want a specific behaviour, I am evaluation everything through my function called gui.eval.

The problem comes when somebody overrides this function. Is there a mechanism to prevent users overriding specific functions?

Comment: No mechanism to prevent this. But you can put it in a package and call it like `pckagename::gui.eval`.

Comment: Why do you think anyone is going to override it in the first place? And if you're certain there are hordes of zombies chanting "gui...evalllll" , then give your GUI a more unusual name.

Answer (score -4):

In fact I was able to answer my question quickly.

There is a mechanism in fact. lockBinding() does the trick and I will remove the unlockBinding function from the R source code.

Comment: “I will remove the unlockBinding function from the R source code.” – that severely cripples the usefulness of your product. Not a good idea. This is a hack, not a real solution. The real solution is to use R packages / namespaces.